# Warning: Undefined array key "action" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_final\app\ajax.php on line 11

Tags: php, jquery, form-data

I have a problem using the FormData of jquery, i can't find a solution, i want to have all the info that i put on my form of adding a game in an array but it says that the array key 'action' is not defined, this is my code in main.js file:

```
var formulario = $(this),
  data = new FormData($(formulario).get(0)),
  action = "add_game";


data.append("action", action);

// AJAX

$.ajax({
  url: "app/ajax.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  contexType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  data: data,
  beforeSend: function () {
    formulario.waitMe();
  }
```

and on my ajax.php file a have a switch that i made to do the action of register login and the one that is giving me problems is to add a game filling a form, this is my code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    json_encode(403);
}

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {

case 'add_game':
    if (!isset($_POST['titulo'], $POST['id_genero'], $_POST['id_platafoma'], $POST['calificacion'], $_POST['opinion'])) {
        json_output(400, 'Completa el fomrulario');
    }


    $nuevo_juego =
        [
            'id_usuario' => logueado()['id'],
            'titulo' => trim($_POST['titulo']),
            'id_genero' => $_POST['id_genero'],
            'id_plataforma' => $_POST['id_plataforma'],
            'calificacion' => $_POST['calificacion'],
            'opinion' => trim($_POST['opinion']),
            'creado' => fecha()

        ];    


    break;
default:
    json_output(403);
    break;
```

can someone help me? i don´t know what is the problem... please!

Comment: `$action = $_POST['action'] ?? null;` if you must, also `json_encode(403);` on it's own does nothing.

Comment: What is `contexType`? Looks like a typo for `contentType`

Comment: `json_encode(403);`? What is this supposed to do? You're not echoing it. I suspect you're trying to set the response code.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @Scuzzy If `action` is always supposed to be passed, that will just hide the problem. We *want* an error if the script is called incorrectly.

Comment: You have an `isset()` test -- if the variable isn't set, you should exit with an error rather than continue to the rest of the code that expects the variable to be set.

Comment: What is `json_output()`? I guess that's what you meant to call in the `if` block, rather than `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Barmar im so stupid yes the problem was that i write contexType instead of contentType. thank you!